# Get yuv size size stored by Mediabuffer

Tags: android, stagefright, openmax

I am use OpenMax to decode the video frame,my sample is like this:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/data/local/tmp/test.yuv", "wb");
while(!isExit)
{
    MediaBuffer *mVideoBuffer;
    MediaSource::ReadOptions options;
    status_t err = mVideoDecoder->read(&mVideoBuffer, &options);
    if (err == OK) 
    {
        if (mVideoBuffer->range_length() > 0) 
        {
            // If video frame availabe, render it to mNativeWindow
            int w = 0;
            int h = 0;
            int dw = 0;
            int dh = 0;
            int stride = 0;
            sp<MetaData> metaData = mVideoBuffer->meta_data();
            sp<MetaData> outFormat = mVideoDecoder->getFormat();

            outFormat->findInt32(kKeyWidth , &w);
            outFormat->findInt32(kKeyHeight, &h);

            int64_t timeUs = 0;
            metaData->findInt64(kKeyTime, &timeUs);
            metaData->findInt32(kKeyDisplayHeight, &dh);
            metaData->findInt32(kKeyDisplayWidth, &dw);
            metaData->findInt32(kKeyStride, &stride);
            printf("out format w:%d h:%d dw:%d dh:%d stride:%d timestamp:%lld\n",
                        w, h, dw, dh, stride, timeUs);

            if(fp)
            {
                printf("decode a frame, range_length = %d range_offset = %d size = %d width = %d height = %d\n",
                            mVideoBuffer->range_length(), mVideoBuffer->range_offset(), mVideoBuffer->size(), w, h);
                fwrite(mVideoBuffer->data( ) + mVideoBuffer->range_offset( ), 1, mVideoBuffer->range_length(), fp);
            }

            metaData->setInt32(kKeyRendered, 1);
        }
        mVideoBuffer->release();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("end of file\n");
        isExit = true;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

the output is like this:

```
out format w:1280 h:720 dw:0 dh:0 stride:0 timestamp:44044
decode a frame, range_length = 1417216 range_offset = 0 size = 1417216 width = 1280 height = 720
```

My question is how to know the yuv realy size stored by the MediaBuffer,
because 1280 x 736 (stride is 32, i guess) x 1.5 = 1413120,but mVideoBuffer's range_length() is 1417216, there is no regular i can get the yuv size, please help me, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaBuffer` which is being read as part `read` method is initialized [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#1948). Please note that the `info.mSize` is set to `def.nBufferSize` which is same as allocated size. This information is not updated to reflect the actual size filled by the decoder.

The allocation is 1280 x 736 x 1.5 with the `height` aligned to 32. The `stride` is really not required as 1280 is a very well aligned number.